# neo4j, nodejs, session expire error, how to fix it?

Tags: node.js, csv, neo4j

I was trying to use neo4j at backend. First I want to import csv to neo4j. (first tried to see how many lines csv file has)
But having problem, the code is following

```
var neo4j = require('neo4j-driver').v1;
var driver = neo4j.driver("bolt://localhost", neo4j.auth.basic("neo4j", "neo4j"));

function createGraphDataBase(csvfilepath) 
{
  var session = driver.session();
  return session
     .run( 'LOAD CSV FROM {csvfilepath} AS line RETURN count(*)', 
         {csvfilepath}
  )
  .then(result => {
     session.close();
     console.log(' %d lines in csv.file', result);
     return result;
  })
  .catch(error => {
    session.close();
    console.log(error);
    return error;
  });
}
```

the "csvfilepath" is the path of csv file, it is as follows.

> '/Users/.../Documents/Project/.../test/spots.csv';
>   is there something wrong with giving path like this?

I am calling that function on other module as

```
 var api = require('./neo4j.js');    
 const csvFile = path.join(__dirname,csvFileName); 
 api.createGraphDataBase(csvFile);
```

I am having error as

> Error: Connection was closed by server
>   ....

I am new to these, please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL that you specify in a `LOAD CSV` clause must be a legal URL.

As stated in [this guide](https://neo4j.com/developer/guide-import-csv/):

> Make sure to use the right URLs esp. file URLs.+ On OSX and Unix use
>   file:///path/to/data.csv, on Windows, please use
>   file:c:/path/to/data.csv

In your case, `csvfilepath` needs to specify the `file:///` protocol (since you seem to be running on OSX) for a local file. Based on your example, the value should be something like this:

```
'file:///Users/.../Documents/Project/.../test/spots.csv'
```