# Session Expired in Neo4j with Node js

Tags: node.js, neo4j

I have looked at the documentation:

- Neo4j https://neo4j.com/developer/javascript/
- NodeJS Driver https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-javascript-driver

I've created a project using these commands:

```
npm install --save neo4j-driver
nano index.js
```

And written this code:

```
var neo4j = require('neo4j-driver').v1;

// Create a driver instance, for the user neo4j with password neo4j.
// It should be enough to have a single driver per database per application.
var driver = neo4j.driver("bolt://localhost:7687", neo4j.auth.basic("neo4j", "123456"));

// Register a callback to know if driver creation was successful:
driver.onCompleted = function() {
    // proceed with using the driver, it was successfully instantiated
    console.log('successfully connected');
};

// Register a callback to know if driver creation failed.
// This could happen due to wrong credentials or database unavailability:
driver.onError = function(error) {
    console.log('Driver instantiation failed', error);
};

// Create a session to run Cypher statements in.
// Note: Always make sure to close sessions when you are done using them!
var session = driver.session();
console.log(session);

session.run("CREATE (TheMatrix:Movie {title:'The Matrix', released:1999, tagline:'Welcome to the Real World'})");

// Close the driver when application exits
driver.close();
```

I get this error message when I run `node index.js`:

> Driver instantiation failed { [Error: socket hang up] code:
>   'SessionExpired' }

I have explored:

- [neo4j, nodejs, session expire error, how to fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42970911/neo4j-nodejs-session-expire-error-how-to-fix-it)
- [Neo4j Javascript Driver Server keeps Expiring Session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41499564/neo4j-javascript-driver-server-keeps-expiring-session)
- [how to fix "connection was closed by sever" in nodejs +neo4j?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42990605/how-to-fix-connection-was-closed-by-sever-in-nodejs-neo4j)
- https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-javascript-driver/issues/187

I have set up my password to be `123456` after the first launch at `http://localhost:7474/browser/`

I'm on Windows 10. Anything I need to do in terms of firewall? What am I missing?

Edit: I'm using Neo4j 3.1.2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that the `session.run` function is asynchronous and returns the promise.

But you close the session until the moment it is executed and ready to return the result.

Try this:

```
var neo4j = require('neo4j-driver').v1;
var driver = neo4j.driver("bolt://localhost:7687",
                          neo4j.auth.basic("neo4j", "123456")
);

driver.onCompleted = function() {
    console.log('successfully connected');
};
driver.onError = function(error) {
    console.log('Driver instantiation failed', error);
};

var session = driver.session();
console.log(session);    
session
    .run(`
        CREATE (TheMatrix:Movie { title:'The Matrix', 
                                  released:1999, 
                                  tagline:'Welcome to the Real World'
        })
        RETURN TheMatrix
    `)
    .then( function(result) {
        console.log(result);
        driver.close();
    })
    .catch( function(error) {
        console.log(error);
        driver.close();
    })
```